# Why does Mongo FETCH on count() with $nin?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, count

I am trying to understand why Mongo can't use a covered index with my query using `$nin`, and how to resolve it.  My issue is with a compound index, but it happens with a simple index too.

Take a simple document:

```
{b: "text1"}
```

And a simple index:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "b" : 1
    },
    "name" : "b_1",
    "ns" : "mytest"
}
```

And what I thought was a simple `count()` query:

```
db.mytest.count( {b: $nin: [ "foo" ]}, {b:1, _id:0} )
```

The `winningPlan` unexpectedly includes a `FETCH`:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "COUNT",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "b" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "b_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "b" : [
                    "[MinKey, \"foo\")",
                    "(\"foo\", MaxKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with a simple equality condition it uses `COUNT_SCAN` (as expected):

```
> db.mytest.count( {b: "bar" }, {b:1, _id:0} )

"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "COUNT",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "b" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "b_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 1
    }
},
```

To make things more interesting, a `find()` instead of a `count()` doesn't look at any documents:

```
> db.mytest.find({b:{ $nin: [ 3 ] }}, {b:1, _id:0})

"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "PROJECTION",
    "transformBy" : {
        "b" : 1,
        "_id" : 0
    },
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "b" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "b_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 1,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
            "b" : [
                "[MinKey, 3.0)",
                "(3.0, MaxKey]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Why does Mongo need to `FETCH` with `$nin`?  It should be able to fulfill this exclusively from the index.

Comment: Possibly related to the [query selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#read-operations-query-selectivity) of `$nin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that this is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27822) that was fixed in 3.6.  There was definitely an unnecessary FETCH in many COUNT situations.